# How to get the ID of a Dijit.Tree entry?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a Dijit.Tree control written as markup code.
Now I'm using the onload eventhandler to go through the `div.dijitTreeRow` (via `dojo.query`) elements and add `img`-Tags to them.

Edit: To be clear, I really want to append `img`-Tags to the row, as I plan on using them as action buttons (with an onclick event).

However, in the `img`-Tag I need the element ID I was passing to the tree earlier via json. I do **not** want the HTML-attribute `id`!

Checking label with store isn't an option as it would then die on duplicate entries.

Overriding tree methods isn't an option either, as I much want to have it to be markup as long far as possible.

So, how do I get the ID back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by `j105rob` on the Dojo IRC Channel (Kudos!).

The easiest way is to overwrite the `dijit.Tree` class and overwrite `_createNode` to fit the needs.
Connecting custom events to the node will likely kill DnD functionality though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the `div.dijitTreeRow` you can access the `div.dijitTreeNode` which corresponds to the `dijit._TreeNode` widget, which will in turn have a `dijit.Tree.item` stored in its `item` property. Once you get a hold on it, you can use the `TreeStoreModel` methods to retrieve the id you want. To get from the DOM node (`div.dijitTreeNode`) to the Dijit widget (`dijit._TreeNode`), use `dijit.byNode()`.

```
// Given rowNode is your div.dijitTreeRow...
var treeNode = dijit.byNode(rowNode.parentNode);
var item = treeNode.item;
var id = model.getIdentity(item);
```

BUT, that's not the correct way to approach the problem. You're basically messing up with the internals of the widget and your code is bound to break randomly on unexpected situations, and with higher probability if you later need to upgrade your Dojo version.

What you really want is to subclass the `dijit.Tree` widget and provide your own `getIconClass/Style`, `getLabelClass/Style` and/or `getRowClass/Style` and add your images through CSS. Why do you say overriding methods is not an option?

If you need more customization than what you can get with CSS (e.g. you want to add buttons or actions to each tree node), you could override the `_createTreeNode` method of `dijit.Tree` and either subclass `dijit._TreeNode` or customize it on the spot. Then again, keep in mind the underscore at the beginning of both the method and the class mean they are private and therefore subject to change in later versions of Dojo.

I'd suggest you take a look at the sources for `Tree.js` and [these](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated) [excellent](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/declare) tutorials for pointers on how to subclass the `_TreeNode` widget.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I'm not trying to change the icon in front of each entry. I'm really trying to append images so they can function as buttons for actions (like edit or delete). Would I somehow be able to achieve that by overriding? Also I don't understand how I would access the dijit._TreeNode instance from the div!?

Comment: I edited my answer with some code to access the `id` from the `div`. As for what you're trying to do, I'd override the `_createTreeNode` method, since you need to add logic to each row and not just images.

Comment: Just added some suggestions on that too.